# BCP neither gives results nor outputs anything when using valid statements but it does throw errors when passing invalid parameters

Tags: rhel, software-installation, database, sqlserver

I have to use **bcp** command-line tool to export data from an *SQL Server* database to a file in a Red Hat server.
I am (apparently) using valid statements but **bcp** is not producing any kind of output/results.
However, when I execute statements with missing or invalid parameters it displays the respective error.
I am looking for the reason of this issue (e.g. defective installation, bad usage of **bcp**, lack of permissions or any other known conflict) and how to fix it.

---

**bcp statement:**

```
bcp fully_qualified_table_name out ./data.txt -c -S server -U user -P password
```

**bcp usage:**

```
usage: /opt/microsoft/bin/bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-t field terminator]     [-r row terminator]
  [-a packetsize]           [-K application intent]
  [-S server name or DSN if -D provided]             [-D treat -S as DSN]
  [-U username]             [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-d database name]
```

**bcp version:**

```
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 11.0.2270.0
```

**SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION`):**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
   May 14 2014 18:34:29
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
   Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

**Distribution:**

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (KornShell).
```

---

## Invalid statements with respective error message (examples).

```
bcp THAT_TUB_ACE.oh_nerd.table_name out ./data.txt -c -S sr._bear -U you_sr. -P pass_sword

    SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
    SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 11001
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
    SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 11001
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
```

...

```
bcp fully_qualified_table_name ./data.txt -c -S valid_server -U valid_user -P bad_word

    bcp fully_qualified_table_name out ./data.txt -c -S valid_server -U valid_user -P bad_word
    SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'valid_user'.
```

## SUMMARY.

The objective is to generate a datafile using the following syntax (or similar):

```
bcp fully_qualified_table_name out ./data.txt -c -S server -U user -P password
```

The facts are:

- When running a valid **bcp** statement there's nothing in the window at all (no output) and no datafile is created.
- I cannot use option `-T` (trusted connection using integrated security) for **bcp** so I have to specify the *server, user and password*.
- Tried `queryout` option on a very simple small table already but still no luck.
- Credentials are valid, I successfully tested them using `sqlcmd` like the following: `sqlcmd -S server -U user -P password -Q 'SELECT * FROM really_small_table'`.
- The **bcp** statements under *"Invalid statements with respective error message (examples)"* section of this question are just examples of invalid statements to show that **bcp** actually does something but giving the expected results.

Comment: I don't know anything about bcp, but reading the usage statement in your Q, is seems to me that the `-c` option wants a "character type" which you don't provide.

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller , there are some options to specify the kind of data **bcp** is dealing with...I am originally intending to use a format file but that adds complexity to the statement so in order to keep it simple I included `-c` option which will make **bcp** to store the exported data as **SQLCHAR** ( a [native file storage type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189110.aspx#Anchor_1) ), no matter if it's whether an integer, a date or any other type. So basically by specifying `-c` you get rid of any datatype consideration and simply store the data as delimited strings.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found on my Debian platform is that the Microsoft ODBC installation process put `libodbc.so` into `/usr/lib64`. This isn't an expected location for libraries and `bcp` cannot find it. But instead of telling you that it can't find a necessary library it simply exits.

Solution for Debian. Your situation should be similar.

1. Find where the installation procedure has put `libodbc.so`:

   ```
   find / -type f -name libodbc.so
   ```
2. Add its directory to a new file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/odbc.conf`. I've invented the name, and on my system `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` is included from `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

   ```
   # Required but not documented by MS ODBC installation for SQL Server
   /usr/lib64
   ```
3. Run `ldconfig` to update the list of library locations
4. Retry the `bcp` command

You will need to be root to perform steps 2 and 3. I assume that's no big deal given that you've managed to install the SQL Server libraries.

Comment: Hi @roaima ... all I can do is up-vote your answer because (after long communication and bureaucratic procedures) the Unix admin team didn't follow up the issue so unfortunately it will remain unsolved :( I couldn't agree more with your original (unedited) answer: this is `wild!`. I appreciate the efforts though :)

Comment: @HectorTorres no problem, I quite understand! (It was a nicely-researched question, by the way.)